# IllegalArgumentException: File must be dbfs or s3n: /

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

```
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = f"wasbs://{blob.storage_account_container}@{blob.storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/",

  mount_point = "/mnt/MLRExtract/",

  extra_configs = {f"fs.azure.account.key.{blob.storage_account_name}.blob.core.windows.net":blob.storage_account_access_key})
```

While creating the mount point I'm facing this below error--

IllegalArgumentException: File must be dbfs or s3n: /

Comment: The syntax that you have used to mount a blob storage container is working without any issue. The error `IllegalArgumentException` indicates that there is something wrong with the values passed (source, mount_point, extra_configs) to the mount method. Please check if all the argument values are given accurately and try again.

Answer (score 1):

This error **`IllegalArgumentException`** mainly occurs something wrong with the syntax. You can follow the below syntax, I reproduce the same thing in my environment, and it is working fine.

**Syntax:**

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net", dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<Scope-Name>",key="Key_Value"))

dbutils.fs.mount(
source = "wasbs://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net/",
mount_point = "/mnt/io24",
extra_configs = {"fs.azure.account.key.<storage-account-name>.blob.core.windows.net":"<storage-account-Access key>"}).
```

[image: Ref1]

**Reference:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access

Comment: I'm on a task and stuck on what approach should I follow. Can u pls help me with it once?